# What is the difference between "patronize" and "infantilize"?

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

Are they synonymous or do they have different meanings?

What would be the differences, however slight?

Here are the dictionary definitions:

**infantilize**

verb (used with object)

> to keep in or reduce to an infantile state;
>   to treat or regard as infantile or immature;

**patronize**
verb

> to behave in an offensively condescending manner toward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **patronize** is to treat a person with a nauseating degree of condescension. The person in question is regarded as vastly inferior in intelligence; willing, perhaps, but quite unable, to learn. One can patronize a child - as a child; but one can also patronize an adult - as an adult, so long as their intelligence level is perceived as vastly inferior.

To **infantilize** is to treat a person as if they were a prepubescent child with no experience whatsoever in worldly matters.

Patronizing:

> Let me put it as kindly as I can. You see, I don't think opera is
>   quite your thing. You have to know a whole bunch of things, including
>   music theory, in order to appreciate opera. There's just no need to
>   waste your money on the subscription.

Infantilizing:

> Come on, sweetie. Honestly? I don't think you're ready to appreciate
>   opera. I don't mean you'll never be able to do so. I mean, you'll need
>   to learn a few tings first ... before you attempt to listen to it,
>   you'll have to learn a few things, and those just might strike you as
>   too intricate. Here, have a cookie.